# angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am converting our angular app to use ES6 Style syntax and after changing all the files i am getting the following error;

angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

When i tried to debug the error the error seems to be coming while creating a service. In angular code this is where the error is happening

```
return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName, caller);
```

i am seeing the serviceName getting passed fine, how ever the caller is undefined and not sure why factory is unable to return the service instance.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `caller` defined?

Comment: That's the angular code not our app code.

Comment: angular.js line 4571 method Name getService(serviceName,caller)) angular version i am using is 1.5.3

Comment: I meant can you show us the code that you converted to es6?

Comment: Why can't you post it? I don't mean copy and paste your whole work, just show how you've defined the factory that's causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry my bad i will generalize the code and will post the code. Adding the code in my next post

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code in my github account. 
https://github.com/mars76/angular-es6

my entry point is app.js

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

import config from './app-config';

import run from './app-run-config';

import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import AppController from './app-controller';

import MyService from './my-service';

import * as serviceModule from './service';

import testDirective from './test-directive';

import muUtil from './util/util.js';
    export default angular.module("my-app", ['ui.router','my-service-module','myUtil'])

        .config(config)

        .run(run)

        .component('testDirective',testDirective())
        .controller('appController', AppController).name;
```

And this has a dependency on module "myUtil"

and here are the contents of that module

./util/util.js

```
import * as utilRun from './util-run.js';
import * as MyService1 from './my-service1.js';
import * as MyService2 from './my-service2.js';

    export default angular.module('myUtil', [])

        .service('MyService1', MyService1)

        .service('MyService2', MyService2)

        .run(utilRun).name;
```

And here are my Services

Service 1:

```
export default class MyService1{
    constructor(){

    }

    init(){
        console.log('In MyService1()');
    }
}
```

Service 2:

```
    export default class MyService2{
    constructor(){

    }

    init(){
        console.log('In MyService2()');
    }
}
```

And the run function of the util module

```
import MyService1 from './my-service1.js';
import MyService2 from './my-service2.js';

export default function utilRun(MyService1,MyService2){

    MyService1.init();
    MyService2.init();

}

utilRun.$inject =['MyService1','MyService2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same Problem. In my case it was just a problem with the imports.

This documentation helped me: [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

The services are exported as `default` and should be imported in your `./util/util.js` as `default` by:

```
import MyService1 from './my-service1.js';
import MyService2 from './my-service2.js';
```

I suggest the error

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
```

had the reason, that the services were `undefined` when imported this way:

```
import * as MyService1 from './my-service1.js';
import * as MyService2 from './my-service2.js';
```

The wildcard import doesn't import defaults. That's the reason why there have to be a special case in the ES6 syntax:

```
import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";
```